# CellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER) error

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
CellStyle stringStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
stringStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

this code produces error:

> method setAlignment in interface CellStyle cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: short
>
> found: HorizontalAlignment
>
> reason: actual argument HorizontalAlignment cannot be converted to short by     method invocation conversion

so I change the code to use a short:

```
CellStyle stringStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
stringStyle.setAlignment((short)1);
```

And my IDE complains saying:

> setAlignment (org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment) in CellStyle cannot be applied to (short)

So it complains that it wants a `short` when I give it a `HorizontalAlignment` and that it wants a `HorizontalAligment` when I give it a `short`.

Comment: I couldn't find a `setAlignment` that takes a `HorizontalAlignment`. Which version of POI are you using?

Comment: @user7 I am using 3.12

Comment: If you have [this method](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html) then your first code snippet should work

Comment: @user7 that's sort of the problem. It doesn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must have different `apache poi` versions in classpath. So your IDE is confused about this.

In `apache poi 3.12` there is  [void setAlignment(short align)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_12_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.java?view=markup#l310) and there is [public final static short ALIGN_CENTER = 0x2;](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_12_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.java?view=markup#l38). So code would be

```
CellStyle stringStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
stringStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

for `apache poi 3.12`.

But since `apache poi 3.15` this method is deprecated and since `apache poi 3.17` it is removed and now only [void setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment align)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setAlignment-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment-) can be used having [HorizontalAlignment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/HorizontalAlignment.html) as the parameter. So code would be

```
CellStyle stringStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
stringStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

for `apache poi 3.17`.

I suspect your problem with your IDE results from the fact, that jars from different versions `apache poi 3.12` and `apache poi 3.17` are in classpath of your IDE. This is not supported and must be avoided.

Comment: I had faced `HorizontalAlignment` undefined error. How to import HorizontalAlignment in coldfusion?

Comment: @Mani7TAM: `\org\apache\poi\ss\usermodel\HorizontalAlignment.class` is in `poi-3.17.jar`. So this jar, and only `poi-*.jar`s from that version `3.17` must be in class path if version `3.17` is used. Also it is in `poi-4.0.1.jar`. So this jar, and only `poi-*.jar`s from that version `4.0.1` must be in class path if version `4.0.1` is used. Mixing jars from different versions is not supported and leads to errors.